# How I make color calibration in opencv using a colorchecker?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I have a image of the colorchecker get by a digital camera, how i use this to calibrate the images using opencv?

follow below the colorchecker image:

[image]

Comment: I guess you mean "color correction" of the pixels here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking how to do color calibration or how to do it with OpenCV?

In order to do color calibration you use the last row (gray tones) of the calibration board. Here is what you should do for color calibration step by step:

1. Capture an image and take small regions inside the gray regions. 10x10 pixels in the middle should be fine. After this step you will have 6 10x10 regions.
2. Take the average value of the 10x10 region for each gray region. After this step you will have 6 average values, 1 for each gray region. And remember, each value is an RGB value, like the values given below each color.
3. Check the average values and try to match the values with given values. In the first try most probably the average values are different then the given values. Actually making them match is the calibration operation. To make them match you should change the gains of your camera. Change gain of each channel and try to match the average values with given values.
4. After you change the camera gains for each channel, repeat these until it converges and camera is calibrated.

You can check if the calibration is done correctly by taking a small region from another color and check its average value with its given value. If they matches or pretty much same, then you have color calibrated your camera successfully.

All you need to do is being able to set camera gains, after that just capture images and try to match values and find correct camera gains.

If you understand the process, doing this using OpenCV should be piece of cake.

**[EDIT]**

Well, I don't know any ways to calculate the gain. But the most easy way is brute force. You can do something like this;

suppose your gain values vary between 0.0 and 3.0, specify a step value such as 0.1 and try all values. You should have a for loop like this:

```
for (double redGain=0.0; redGain <= 3.0; redGain += 0.1)
   for (double greenGain=0.0; greenGain <= 3.0; greenGain += 0.1)
      for (double blueGain=0.0; blueGain<= 3.0; blueGain+= 0.1)
         setCameraGain(redGain, greenGain, bluegain);
         // do the rest of the stuff
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: but how I calculate this gain, for example if I obtain average in the first RGB(250,250,250) and the given values is (246,246,247), difference (4,4,3) and the second (200,200,200) and the given values is (207,207,209) resulting in (-7,-7,-9). What would be the gain, this could be the average between the differences obtained?

Comment: You describe a somewhat strange white balance algorithm. This is quite different from color calibration

Comment: @RosaGronchi then I'll be glad if you can tell the correct color calibration?

Comment: that depends on the input, but assuming you have the raw (demosaiced) image, you need to compute a 3x3 matrix that maps the camera colors to your preferred color space (e.g. sRGB). That is at least the first order approximation.

Comment: @RosaGronchi Can you set this up as a least squares problem that solves for a the 3x3 matrix elements that make the observed colors match the known colors as best as possible?

Comment: @RosaGronchi do you still available to comment about this matter? Could you please elaborate a little bit more? I am quite interested on that matter. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing but couldn't find a proper solution on the internet, so this is my solution:

Plot every colour point of every axis and find [curve fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165259/python-numpy-scipy-curve-fitting) line between the input and output (referance) using np.polyfit.

Convert those curve lines into LUT (look up table) and that's it.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##################################################################################
# polynomial function
################################################################################## 
def polynomialFit(x, y):
    # calculate polynomial
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3) # 3 degree polynomial fit
    f = np.poly1d(z) # create a function

    # calculate new x's and y's
    x_new = np.arange(256)
    y_new = np.clip(f(x_new),0,255)
    return y_new

##################################################################################
# main
################################################################################## 
# output color (based on wiki)
outpt = [[115, 82, 68], [194, 150, 130], [98, 122, 157], [87, 108, 67], [133, 128, 177], [103, 189, 170],
        [214, 126, 44], [80, 91, 166], [193, 90, 99], [94, 60, 108], [157, 188, 64], [224, 163, 46],
        [56, 61, 150], [70, 148, 73], [175, 54, 60], [231, 199, 31], [187, 86, 149], [8, 133, 161],
        [243, 243, 242], [200, 200, 200], [160, 160, 160], [122, 122, 122], [85, 85, 85], [52, 52, 52]]

# input color (based on your image)
inpt = [[68, 41, 32], [143, 100, 84], [52, 79, 109], [41, 60, 32], [75, 78, 119], [50, 121, 113],
        [171, 81, 21], [34, 55,134], [152, 42, 55], [46, 26, 54], [100, 130, 34], [153, 107, 22],
        [16, 35, 111], [38, 113, 48], [138, 20, 26], [160, 145, 18], [144, 43, 95], [ 24, 88, 124],
        [180, 182, 181], [154, 156, 157], [119, 120, 122], [72, 76, 75], [39, 43, 44], [20, 21, 23]]

outpt = np.array(outpt)
inpt = np.array(inpt)

# calculate polynomial fitting
lineR = polynomialFit(inpt[:,0], outpt[:,0])
lineG = polynomialFit(inpt[:,1], outpt[:,1])
lineB = polynomialFit(inpt[:,2], outpt[:,2])

# plot input output RGB lines
line = np.arange(256)
plt.plot(line, lineR, label = "Red", color='red')
plt.plot(line, lineG, label = "Green", color='green')
plt.plot(line, lineB, label = "Blue", color='blue')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# look up table from polyline
lutR = np.uint8(lineR)
lutG = np.uint8(lineG)
lutB = np.uint8(lineB)

# read image
img = cv2.imread('5XXkM.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (600, 400), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# generate output image using look up table
res = img.copy()
res[:,:,0] = lutB[img[:,:,0]]
res[:,:,1] = lutG[img[:,:,1]]
res[:,:,2] = lutR[img[:,:,2]]

# show result
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('res', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

RGB curve line:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJH3M.png)

Result image after calibration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TTYQ.jpg)

Referance image (wiki):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ7gi.jpg)

I used RGB colour space for this, but you may use LAB or LUV for more accurate human perception.

Comment: What's the purpose of the image '5XXkm.jpg' on the line 'img = cv2.imread('5XXkM.jpg')? Is that meant as a placeholder for any image we want to apply the calculated transform to?

Comment: I calculate the Root Mean Square of the polynomial fit and I got 13? Seems hig to me. Would you know of ways to "improve" the fit?

Comment: 5XXkm.jpg is the name of the image of the colorchecker that was asked by aliel, using other images would not work, you'll need to measure the rgb values on your own colorchecker

Comment: The program used 3rd degree polynomial, you could use other types of fitting or even neural network if you want a flexible fit