# python numpy/scipy curve fitting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I have some points and I am trying to fit curve for this points. I know that there exist `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` function, but I do not understand the documentation, i.e. how to use this function.

My points:

```py
np.array([(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (9, 3)])
```

Can anybody explain how to do that?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I suggest you to start with simple polynomial fit, [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) tries to fit a function `f` that you must know to a set of points.

This is a simple 3 degree polynomial fit using `numpy.polyfit` and `poly1d`, the first performs a least squares polynomial fit and the second calculates the new points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (9, 3)])
# get x and y vectors
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works only with given dataset. But when I change points, in the majority of cases there is only curve between two points. Why?

Comment: It works with any dataset as long as you provide the data correctly, that is two arrays of the same size, for example: `x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` and `y = np.array([0.2, 1, 1.2, 3, 0.8, 1.1])`

Comment: It draws only curve between two lines with following dataset:

x = np.array([0., 1., -1., .5])
y = np.array([0., 1., .9, .7])

Comment: What is difference that it one case it draws correct curve while in other only line between points?

Comment: The problem is that your `x` array is not sorted, and therefore the polyfit is not working, you must reorder both arrays properly: `x = np.array([-1., 0., .5, 1.])` and `y = np.array([.9, 0., .7, 1.])`

Comment: @jabaldonedo Very nice example, is it possible to fit also data with error bars?

Comment: An alternative to sorting your x vals: `x_new = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 50)`

Comment: could you explain `x_new` and `y_new`? What does calculating new xs and ys mean?

Comment: In this specific case, a polynomial fit is a bit of overkill. The data is overfitted, at least for 3 degree polyniomial. Just a horizontal line seems to be more realisitic.

Comment: can you do a polynomial fit in N dimensions?

Comment: Note that the docs recommend using [numpy.polynomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit) over [numpy.polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) since numpy version 1.4

Comment: You haven't explain each step; e.g. how do you define the linspace?

Answer (score 61):

You'll first need to separate your numpy array into two separate arrays containing x and y values.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 9]
y = [1, 4, 1, 3]
```

curve_fit also requires a function that provides the type of fit you would like. For instance, a linear fit would use a function like

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b
```

`scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y)` will return a numpy array containing two arrays: the first will contain values for `a` and `b` that best fit your data, and the second will be the covariance of the optimal fit parameters.

Here's an example for a linear fit with the data you provided.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 9])
y = np.array([1, 4, 1, 3])

def fit_func(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b

params = curve_fit(fit_func, x, y)

[a, b] = params[0]
```

This code will return `a = 0.135483870968` and `b = 1.74193548387`

Here's a plot with your points and the linear fit... which is clearly a bad one, but you can change the fitting function to obtain whatever type of fit you would like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`np.polyfit` fits a polynomial function to data (which is always a good starting point) but `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` is much more flexible because you can fit any function you want to the data ([Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165437/19123103) also mentions this).

For example, to fit a polynomial function of degree 3, initialize a polynomial function `poly3d` and pass it off to `curve_fit` to compute its coefficients using the training values, `x` and `y`. Once you have `coefs_poly3d` computed, you can plug in other values to generate fitted values and plot a general function "around" the original training values. The following code produces the very same plot in [jabaldonedo's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165440/19123103).

```py
def poly3d(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*x + c*x**2 + d*x**3

# initial data to fit
x, y = np.array([(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (9, 3)]).T
# fit poly3d to x, y
coefs_poly3d, _ = curve_fit(poly3d, x, y)

# initialize some points
x_data = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 50)
# transform x_data to y-axis values via poly3d
y_data = poly3d(x_data, *coefs_poly3d)
# plot the points
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', x_data, y_data);
```

As mentioned before, `curve_fit` is more flexible in that you can fit any function. For example, looking at the data, it seems we can fit a sine function as well. Then simply initialize a sine function and pass it to `curve_fit` to compute `coefs_sine`.

Note that since `curve_fit` is an iterative algorithm, choosing an appropriate initial guess for the parameters (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) is sometimes crucial for the algorithm to converge. In the example below, it is initialized by `p0=[0, 0, -2, 0]`. You can, of course, make an educated guess by trial-and-error by plotting the data with different coefficients.

```py
def sine(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*np.sin(-x*c + d)

# fit data to `sine` function
coefs_sine, _ = curve_fit(sine, x, y, p0=[0, 0, -2, 0])
```

Using the very same setup as before (`x`, `y` and `x_data` defined as in `poly3d` case), `sine` produces the following graph:

[image: sine]

###### Which function fits the data better?

A common way to check goodness-of-fit is to compare the mean squared error (i.e. MSE) of the fitted values. It basically computes how far away from the actual data is the fitted values are; closer the better, so small MSE values are good. For the example at hand, if we compare the MSE of the two functions (`sine` and `poly3d`), `sine` fits the data better (because its MSE is smaller).

```py
def mse(func, x, y, coefs):
    return np.mean((func(x, *coefs) - y)**2)

mse_sine = mse(sine, x, y, coefs_sine)
mse_poly3d = mse(poly3d, x, y, coefs_poly3d)
```

N.B. This post is only about fitting a function to an existing data. No attempts were made to build predictive models (in which case, how the function fares depends on how it performs on unseen data and both functions here are probably very overfit).