# Code to resemble a rowing stroke

Tags: python, plot, spline, smoothing

I'm working on a small program displaying moving rowing boats. The following shows a simple sample code (Python 2.x):

```
import time
class Boat:
    def __init__(self, pace, spm):
        self.pace = pace  #velocity of the boat in m/s
        self.spm = spm    #strokes per minute
        self.distance = 0 #distance travelled

    def move(self, deltaT):
        self.distance = self.distance + (self.pace * deltaT)

boat1 = Boat(3.33, 20)
while True:
    boat1.move(0.1)
    print boat1.distance
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

As you can see a boat has a pace and rows with a number of strokes per minute. Everytime the method `move(deltaT)` is called it moves a certain distance according to the pace.

The above boat just travels at a constant pace which is not realistic. A real rowing boat accelerates at the beginning of a stroke and then decelerates after the rowing blades left the water. There are many graphs online which show a typical rowing curve (force shown here, velocity looks similar):

[image: Rowing Stroke Graph]
Source: [highperformancerowing.net](http://highperformancerowing.net/journal/2011/11/17/comparison-of-rowing-on-a-concept-2-stationary-and-dynamic-e.html)

The pace should be constant over time, but it should change during the stroke.

What is the best way to change the constant velocity into a curve which (at least basically) resembles a more realistic rowing stroke?

*Note: Any ideas on how to tag this question better? Is it an algorithm-problem?*

Comment: Use spline interpolation, e.g., from SciPy.

Comment: See also the SE site for statistics http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: And the smoothing transform stat_smooth in ggplot library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to simply come up with something visually plausible and not to do a full physical simulation, you can simply add a sine wave to the position.

```
class Boat:
    def __init__(self, pace, spm, var=0.5):
        self.pace = pace    #average velocity of the boat in m/s
        self.sps = spm/60.0 #strokes per second
        self.var = var      #variation in speed from 0-1
        self.totalT = 0     #total time
        self.distance = 0   #distance traveled

    def move(self, deltaT):
        self.totalT += deltaT
        self.distance = self.pace * (self.totalT + self.var * math.sin(self.totalT * self.sps * 2*math.pi)
```

You need to be careful with the variation `var`, if it gets too high the boat might go backwards and destroy the illusion.

Comment: The result of the code works, as I've tested a rower with a speed of 10m/s and a SPM of 20 rows 30m in a stroke: https://ideone.com/wHjZs3
The velocity during the stroke however seems to jump back and forth. Any ideas what's wrong in the calculation? Don't we have to put the pace into a sine wave instead of time?

Comment: @MOnsDaR sorry, I had a correction that I made but didn't copy into the answer. The `/ self.sps` should be `* self.sps`.

Comment: That did the trick, values now are increasing/decreasing along a sine wave: https://ideone.com/2Cb6u8 However the curve is exactly reverse to what I would expect: It starts fast, goes slower, ends fast. It should be the other way around. I played around with the equation but couldn't get it to run correctly, could you help out one last time?

Comment: @MOnsDaR try using `(1-cos(...))*0.5` instead of `sin(...)`. Edit: scratch that, just inverting the `sin` works better. You need to reduce the variation though to keep from going backwards. See https://ideone.com/L50x5V

Comment: Ha, just found that myself and wanted to post it here :) Thanks a lot for your help, boats are rowing now while looking realistically

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a curve like this into a polynomial equation for velocity.

A description/example of how to do this can be found at:

[python numpy/scipy curve fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165259/python-numpy-scipy-curve-fitting)

This shows you how to take a set of x,y coordinates (which you can get by inspection of your existing plot or from actual data) and create a polynomial function.

If you are using the same curve for each Boat object, you could just hard code it into your program. But you could also have a separate polynomial equation for each Boat object as well, assuming each rower or boat has a different profile.

Comment: Just noticed your graph has Force on the y-axis. Force is mass*acceleration. Since your mass is constant, it's essentially a plot of acceleration (not velocity).

Comment: This is a good advanced approach, it's probably a bit complex for now. I'll take this into consideration when my application needs a more sophisticated solution

Answer (score 1):

You can perform simple integration of the differential equation of motion. (This is what you are already doing to get space as a function of time, with constant speed, `x' = x + V.dt`.)

Assume a simple model with a constant force during the stroke and no force during the glide, and drag proportional to the speed.

So the acceleration is `a = P - D.v` during stroke, and `- D.v` during glide (deceleration).

The speed is approximated with `v' = v + a.dt`.

The space is approximated with `x' = x + v.dt`.

If `dt` is sufficiently small, this motion should look realistic. You can refine the model with a more accurate force law and better integration techniques like Runge-Kutta, but I am not sure it is worth it.

Below an example plot of speed and space vs time using this technique. It shows speed oscillations quickly establishing a periodic regime, and quasi-linear displacement with undulations.

[image]

Comment: I guess this is a good enough overall solution. However my question is more meant to ask for "How can I model the curve to be like a rowing stroke, but keep the overall pace".