# Fitting a power law with known exponent and extracting the coefficient in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, power-law

I have a data set that I know fits to a curve of the form:

```
y = a x²
```

and I want to extract the value of `a`.

What's the best way to go about this in Python (with scipy etc.) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python numpy/scipy curve fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165259/python-numpy-scipy-curve-fitting)

Comment: There are tons of posts on SO that show how to do this. Just google for `python curve_fit` or `python lmfit` and you will find plenty of examples. If you then run into issues with the implementation, post your code and data and describe the actual problem you face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a graphical fitter example using scipy's curve_fit():

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7])
yData = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 60.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7])


def func(x, a):
    return (a * numpy.square(x))


# same as the scipy default
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```